# Class 'Cassandra' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php

Tags: php, cassandra, xampp

I am executing the following code on the xampp server:-

```
<?php
$cluster   = Cassandra::cluster() 
             ->build();
$keyspace  = 'system';
$session   = $cluster->connect($keyspace);    
?>
```

but I get the error -  Class 'Cassandra' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 3.

I have copied the Cassandra.dll file in php->ext folder of xampp.I have even tried writing the command Use Cassandra but it was of no use.
Please help me out!!!

Comment: Did you add `extension=php_cassandra.dll` in your `php.ini`?

Comment: Yes I have added the command. I downloaded the prebuilt php_cassandra.dll from - http://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/windows/cassandra/1.2.2/.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are experiencing might be due to an incorrect build version for the XAMPP version you are using. The PHP version, architecture, VC compiler, and thread safety (enable/disabled) all need to match for the extension that you are using. To determine the exact needs you can execute the following commands:

- `php -i | FINDSTR /C:"PHP Version"`
- `php -i | FINDSTR /C:"Architecture"`
- `php -i | FINDSTR /C:"Compiler"`
- `php -i | FINDSTR /C:"Thread Safety"`

  - TS  = Thread Safety => enabled
  - NTS = Thread Safety => disabled

As an example I tested the [standalone XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.0.15/xampp-win32-7.0.15-0-VC14.7z/download) that utilized PHP v7.0.15; x86 and TS (Thread Safety => enabled). Based on the archive naming convention you can skip the `php -i` lookups and determine the architecture is x86 using the VC14 compiler. The thread safety is not obvious from the archive name but can be determined running the above command; this particular XAMPP is TS.

With that information you will be able to determine that the driver archive required for this particular XAMPP is [`cassandra-php-driver-1.2.2-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.zip`](http://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/windows/cassandra/1.2.2/cassandra-php-driver-1.2.2-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.zip). After the archive has been downloaded and the `php_cassandra.dll` has been placed in the `xampp\php\ext` directory you will need to modify the `php.ini` file with the following:

```
[cassandra]
extension=php_cassandra.dll
```

To verify the extension is being loaded properly you can enter either of the following commands:

- `php -i | FINDSTR /C:"Cassandra support"` or
- `php -m` and look for `cassandra` module

NOTE: Using [CCM](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) to create a single node cluster for Apache Cassandra v3.10 and your example code no issues were discovered.